# Conditional expressions in JMustache

Tags: java, mustache

Despite [JMustache](https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache) being a logic-less template framework, I wonder if it is possible to use some basic expressions in the view. For example if I want to highlight the rows whose tasks are high priority, with JSP templates I can compare the priority using Expression Language (EL):

```
<c:if test="${task.priority == Priority.HIGH}">
    <b>
        <c:out value="${task.priority}" />
    </b>
</c:if>
```

However, with JMustache to get same result, I have to precalculate the boolean value in the Controller layer as you can see [here](https://github.com/wearearima/java-web-templates/blob/develop/src/main/java/eu/arima/MustacheTask.java#L20) and [here](https://github.com/wearearima/java-web-templates/blob/develop/src/main/java/eu/arima/TemplatesController.java#L45). Afterwards, I can check the boolean value in the Mustache template in this way:

```
{{#highPriority}}
    <td><b>{{task.priority}}</b></td>
{{/highPriority}}
```

My question is, can I do comparisons with Mustache like I do in JSP? For example,

```
{{#task.priority == Priority.HIGH}}
    <td><b>{{task.priority}}</b></td>
{{/highPriority}}
```

If not, does [Handlebars template](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java) framework provide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these template engines are logic-less, so you can't do comparisons out of the box.

You can, however, register helpers and implement your own version of logic. There's a sample implementation over at https://gist.github.com/doginthehat/1890659. Per SO standards, I'm copying it here, but want to credit `doginthehat` for the work:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function(lvalue, rvalue, options) {

    if (arguments.length < 3)
        throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' needs 2 parameters");

    var operator = options.hash.operator || "==";

    var operators = {
        '==':       function(l,r) { return l == r; },
        '===':  function(l,r) { return l === r; },
        '!=':       function(l,r) { return l != r; },
        '<':        function(l,r) { return l < r; },
        '>':        function(l,r) { return l > r; },
        '<=':       function(l,r) { return l <= r; },
        '>=':       function(l,r) { return l >= r; },
        'typeof':   function(l,r) { return typeof l == r; }
    }

    if (!operators[operator])
        throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' doesn't know the operator "+operator);

    var result = operators[operator](lvalue,rvalue);

    if( result ) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }

});
```

Your use case would look like:

```
{{#compare task.priority Priority.HIGH operator="==="}}
    <td><b>{{task.priority}}</b></td>
{{/compare}}
```

Comment: I had seen the doingthehat's implementation but I wondered if Mustache had something similar by default. Thanks for your answer.